# Passing string to curl without literal double quotes

Tags: bash, curl, double-quotes

I am trying to write a shell script that invokes two APIs using curl.

One of the keys of JSON output of the first curl is passed to the second curl. In the Bash script below, I am passing token as a command line parameter to the first curl and it works fine.

The output of the first curl is extracted into `client_token` and I am passing it to the second curl. It is failing.

The reason being, wherever I have `$client_token`, the value is getting substituted as `"value"`  (with quotes) instead of `value` (without quotes). Curl expects strings without quotes in the second curl. How can I get rid of double quotes?

```
echo $1
XVaultToken=`curl -X POST  "https://sub.domain.tld:8200/login"   -d '{"token":"'"$1"'"}'` 
client_token=`echo $XVaultToken|jq '.auth.client_token' 
echo $client_token
apiKey=`curl -X GET https://sub.domain.tld:8200/api-key  -H 'X-Vault-Token: "'"$client_token"'"'`
#apiKey=`curl -X GET https://sub.domain.tld:8200/api-key  -H 'X-Vault-Token: $client_token'`
echo "apikey"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your `jq` command is outputting the quotes that you don't want. Ask `jq` for the raw value instead:

```
client_token=`echo $XVaultToken|jq -r '.auth.client_token'
```